# Working on two different workbooks, can't access the second worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a program to compare if there's a match between my ThisWorkbook and other workbook. It is doing everything fine except when the code should find the text in the second worksheet of the other workbook. It will iterate till it crashes. The text cell i am trying to find exists in both files but for some reason my code can't identify it (i've verified the format, both are in text format)

The crash occurs in this line `Case taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 4) = transf1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 1)`:

The error is: Run-time error 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error

```
    Dim consultaWbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim linhas1Wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim linhas2Wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim transf1Wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim transf2Wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim taxasWks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lin_dest As Long
    Dim lin_ori_1 As Long
    Dim lin_ori_2 As Long




    Set consultaWbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Feels Bad Man\Dropbox\Tesingz\tesingz\Com paineis de transformador - versao 2.xlsm")

    Set linhas1Wks = consultaWbk.Worksheets("Taxas linhas")
    Set linhas2Wks = consultaWbk.Worksheets("Tempo médio de reposição linhas")
    Set transf1Wks = consultaWbk.Worksheets("Taxas Transformadores")
    Set transf2Wks = consultaWbk.Worksheets("Tempo médio de reposição transf")
    Set taxasWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("taxas falha temp med rep")

     lin_dest = 2
     lin_ori_1 = 2
     lin_ori_2 = 2


    Do While taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 1) <> ""

            Select Case True

            Case taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 4).Value2 = linhas1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 1).Value2:

                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 5).Value2 = linhas1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 3).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 6).Value2 = linhas1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 4).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 7).Value2 = linhas1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 5).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 8).Value2 = linhas1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 6).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 9).Value2 = linhas1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 7).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 10).Value2 = linhas2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 2).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 11).Value2 = linhas2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 3).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 12).Value2 = linhas2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 4).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 13).Value2 = linhas2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 5).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 14).Value2 = linhas2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_1, 6).Value2

                 lin_dest = lin_dest + 1
                 lin_ori_1 = 2


            Case Else:

                 lin_ori_1 = lin_ori_1 + 1

            End Select


                Select Case True

                Case taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 4).Value2 = transf1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 1).Value2:

                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 5).Value2 = transf1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 2).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 6).Value2 = transf1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 3).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 7).Value2 = transf1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 4).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 8).Value2 = transf1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 5).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 9).Value2 = transf1Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 6).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 10).Value2 = transf2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 2).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 11).Value2 = transf2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 3).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 12).Value2 = transf2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 4).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 13).Value2 = transf2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 5).Value2
                 taxasWks.Cells(lin_dest, 14).Value2 = transf2Wks.Cells(lin_ori_2, 6).Value2


                 lin_dest = lin_dest + 1
                 lin_ori_2 = 2


                Case Else:

                    lin_ori_2 = lin_ori_2 + 1

                End Select


Loop


    Set linhas1Wks = Nothing
    Set linhas2Wks = Nothing
    Set transf1Wks = Nothing
    Set transf2Wks = Nothing
    consultaWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False


    Set consultaWbk = Nothing

    MsgBox "END"


End Sub
```

Comment: instead of looping endlessly, read about using `Find` and `FindNext`. it will speed up your code's run-time a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never liked these sort of Do While loops that keep looping until they find a blank. If no match is found, lin_ori_1 and lin_ori_2 will continue to iterate until they exceed the number of rows on a worksheet as they are only independently reset to 2 is a match has been found.

```
Dim fnd As Variant
With taxasWks
    For lin_dest = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        fnd = Application.Match(.Cells(lin_dest, 4).Value2, linhas1Wks.Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(fnd) Then
            'a match was found
            .Cells(lin_dest, 5) = linhas1Wks.Cells(fnd , 3).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 6) = linhas1Wks.Cells(fnd , 4).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 7) = linhas1Wks.Cells(fnd , 5).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 8) = linhas1Wks.Cells(fnd , 6).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 9) = linhas1Wks.Cells(fnd , 7).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 10) = linhas2Wks.Cells(fnd , 2).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 11) = linhas2Wks.Cells(fnd , 3).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 12) = linhas2Wks.Cells(fnd , 4).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 13) = linhas2Wks.Cells(fnd , 5).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 14) = linhas2Wks.Cells(fnd , 6).Value2
        End If
        fnd = Application.Match(.Cells(lin_dest, 4).Value2, transf1Wks.Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(fnd) Then
            'a match was found
            .Cells(lin_dest, 5) = transf1Wks.Cells(fnd , 2).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 6) = transf1Wks.Cells(fnd , 3).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 7) = transf1Wks.Cells(fnd , 4).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 8) = transf1Wks.Cells(fnd , 5).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 9) = transf1Wks.Cells(fnd , 6).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 10) = transf2Wks.Cells(fnd , 2).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 11) = transf2Wks.Cells(fnd , 3).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 12) = transf2Wks.Cells(fnd , 4).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 13) = transf2Wks.Cells(fnd , 5).Value2
            .Cells(lin_dest, 14) = transf2Wks.Cells(fnd , 6).Value2
        End If
    Next lin_dest
End With
```

Don't assign a value to the .Value2 property; assign another cell's .Value2 to the default .Value.

Comment: Ok, i am kind of new to excel-vba programming and i am trying to improve. I have seen the function With before but i never understood how it worked. Everything you did went right and it runs really quick right now. WOW
Thanks for the help, i'll study this code so i can improve!

Comment: Essentially, the `With taxasWks ... End With` block means that any `.Cells(...)` within the block belong to the taxasWks worksheet.

Comment: Additionally, don't try to use `Application.Worksheet.Match` or `Worksheet.Match`. To catch an error into a variant you require `Application.Match`.